# Small error while passing command line arguments to a Python script using argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

This is the code so far:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
if args == 'a':
    _funct1()
elif args == 'b':
    _funct2()
```

I want the user to be able to call this script in such a way that

```
#python script_name -a
```

executes function 1

```
#python script_name -b
```

executes function 2

Comment: is it simply that you are missing `import argparse`

Comment: No, I have imported it. The error is: Unrecognized argument -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, the correct code is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', help='blah a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--ball', help='blah b', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.all:
    _all()
elif args.ball:
    _ball()
```